# Create a select tag by comparing the input in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve this:

In an html form, a text input is required. If the text input = "abc", then select tag is added to the page to create a related dropdown menu. However if it is anything else, there is no dropdown menu or it is disabled.

I can't find or think of a way of doing this with jQuery. Is there an event which compares input string that can be used with $("#equipment").on("???", function()? Thanks.

I'm very new to javascript and jQuery so sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: If the user enters "abc" and that only, no more and no less, then only the dropdown should appear.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the `input` event for the text input, and then hide or show a select element based on the value, something like

```
$('#some_text_input').on('input', function() {

    if ( this.value === 'abc' ) {
        $('#some_select').show();
    } else {
        $('#some_select').hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: will the form have to be submitted so that this occurs?

Comment: No, the `input` event happens whenever the input changes.